# Powershell Command Will not run in C#

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server-2010

I am writing a c# Windows Form app to migrate Exchange 2010 mailboxes to a file location on the server in .pst format. I used an example from the Powershell SDK (Runspace05) to access the exchange cmdlets (Get-Mailbox) and populate a combo-box with the users mailboxes with no problem.

The parts i'm having trouble with is getting the New-MailboxExportRequest cmdlet (the cmdlet that performs the export) to run and the ability to return it's objects and show them in a listbox control. What am I missing? Thanks in advance for your help.

The Code:

```
InitialSessionState iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
        PSSnapInException warning;
        iss.ImportPSSnapIn("Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010", out warning);
        using (Runspace myrunspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(iss))
        {
            myrunspace.Open();
            using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                var mailbox = cmbEmailUserName.Text;
                var pstFile = txtFileSaveLocation.Text;
                const int badLimit = 100; //can be increased in necessary

                powershell.AddCommand("Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010\\New-MailboxExportRequest");
                powershell.AddParameter("Mailbox", mailbox);
                powershell.AddParameter("FilePath", pstFile);

                powershell.Runspace = myrunspace;                 
                Collection<PSObject> results = powershell.Invoke();

                foreach (PSObject thisResult in results)
                        {
                            lstBoxStatus.Items.Add(thisResult);
                        }
        myrunspace.Close();

            }
        }
```

Comment: What sort of information do you want in the ListBox?  Do you want the raw oject and then you format the properies or do you want the output that PowerShell would generate?  If it is the latter, AddCommand("Out-String") to the end of the pipeline to get a PowerShell formatted string as the result.

Comment: When you run the command in the exchange management shell it returns a status... shows that the command has been queued up. I want to return that status in the window.

Comment: If you just want to see the status as PowerShell displays it, then put a `powershell.AddCommand("Out-String")` after the last AddParameter above.  The result you get will be a string but that string should contain the status as PowerShell would have displayed it.

Answer (score 1):

You want to access the properties of the `PSObject`, not the object itself.

Try this:

```
foreach (PSObject thisResult in results)
{
    foreach (PSPropertyInfo thisResultInfo in thisResult.Properties)
    {
        lstBoxStatus.Items.Add("Name: {0} Value: {1} Type: {2}", thisResultInfo.Name, thisResultInfo.Value, thisResultInfo.MemberType);
    }
}
```

Comment: VS didn't like your code the way it was written so I had to modify it to get it to compile. However it did not produce the expected outcome. Here is my edit to your code:


    foreach (PSObject thisResult in results)
{
    foreach (PSPropertyInfo thisResultInfo in thisResult.Properties)
    {
        lstBoxStatus.Items.Add(string.Format("Name: {0} Value: {1} Type: {2}", thisResultInfo.Name, thisResultInfo.Value, thisResultInfo.MemberType));
    }
}

Comment: What is wrong with the output from your modification? You may need to access the value with something like `thisResult.Members[thisResultInfo.Name].Value`

Comment: The modification didn't produce any output... which leaves scratching my head.

Comment: Check powershell.HadErrors. Maybe there are no results, because there is an error in the command you are executing. Are you sure the command shouldn't be just New-MailboxExportRequest and not with the snapin name in front of it? Or did it produce some PSObjects, just no properties?